# Tuning performance in Windows Services for NFS -- slow write performance from client to server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vmware-esxi, nfs

Background: I'm using a NFS datastore in esxi5.1 to do some ghettoVCB backups.  The NFS share resides on a Windows Server 2008R2 box, using Windows Services for NFS to distribute the share.  Writes to disk over the network are reaching a maximum of around 13MB/s, which is awfully slow -- the kicker is that network traffic from the client is greater than the write speed to disk, so a cache is being built in the backend that doesn't catch up until after the transfer is "finished".

Once the transfer finishes and network traffic declines to the host, write speed to disk spikes to 40MB/s until the write operation is complete.

I have been searching around for performance tuning in regards to write caching, however I am not entirely sure that is what is causing the delay and slow write speeds.

Can anyone offer some direction, or insight into what I need to check?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give a little more info on 1) the hardware on the NFS box (drive type/spindle count/cache size/controller config/etc) and 2) The networking connecting the two (switch type/jumbo frames?/link speed/vSwitch config)

Comment: If anyone found a solution on this, please post it as a comment or an answer!